# Controllers are not defined in karma unit test case

Tags: karma-runner, angular-seed

i get this error when i run the test cases:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'testcont' is not a function, got undefined
```

This is my ControllerSpec.js

```
describe('controllers', function(){
  var scope;   
  beforeEach(angular.module('myapp.test'));   
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){    
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('testcont', {$scope:scope});
  }));

  it('should', function(){
      expect(scope.a).toBe(10)      
  })

});
```

This is my controllers.js

```
angular.module('myapp.test', [], function () {

}).controller('testcont', function($scope) {
    $scope.a = 10;
});
```

**Log Content**

```
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin karma-junit-reporter.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin karma-chrome-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin karma-firefox-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin karma-jasmine.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining ).
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
DEBUG [launcher]: Creating temp dir at C:\Users\RAJSUB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-48416683
DEBUG [launcher]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\Users\RAJSUB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-48416683 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --start-maximized http://localh
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/lib/angular/angular.js
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/app.js
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/controllers.js
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/directives.js
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/filters.js
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/services.js
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/controllersSpec.js
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/directivesSpec.js
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/filtersSpec.js
        C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/servicesSpec.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/lib/angular/angular.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit"
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/lib/angular/angular.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluding C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/config/karma.conf.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/filters.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/controllers.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/app.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/services.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/directivesSpec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/filtersSpec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/directives.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/controllersSpec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/servicesSpec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\seed\node_modules\karma\static/client.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\seed\node_modules\karma\static/karma.js
DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket Uj4-OIYPhAr0oyLxH6vm
INFO [Chrome 30.0.1599 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket Uj4-OIYPhAr0oyLxH6vm
DEBUG [karma]: All browsers are ready, executing
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\seed\node_modules\karma\static/context.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/app.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/controllers.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/lib/angular/angular.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/controllersSpec.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/filters.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/directives.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/filtersSpec.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/js/services.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/directivesSpec.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/servicesSpec.js
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Windows 7) controllers should FAILED
        Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'testcont' is not a function, got undefined
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/ng/areq?p0=testcont&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
            at C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12
            at assertArg (C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1246:11)
            at assertArgFn (C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1256:3)
            at C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/lib/angular/angular.js:5899:9
            at null.<anonymous> (C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:14:5)
            at Object.invoke (C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/app/lib/angular/angular.js:3374:28)
            at workFn (C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:2082:20)
        Error: Declaration Location
            at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:2068:25)
            at null.<anonymous> (C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:12:16)
            at C:/inetpub/wwwroot/seed/test/unit/controllersSpec.js:5:1
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.26 secs / 0.028 secs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using angular.module redefines the module `myapp.test`.
You should use angular.mock.module (which is also set on the window object), i.e.:

```
beforeEach(module('myapp.test'));
```

Comment: I changed to `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myapp.controllers'));` in the testSpec but i still get the same error.

Comment: Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/9Rz5b/).
It has your code and successfully runs the test.

Comment: But my project is a angular seed project. So when i run `scripts\test` in command line im getting the error. Is it something because of `angular seed` or `karma`?

Comment: Try running karma with --log-level debug option. Can you post the log content?

Comment: i have posted the log content in the question section. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks its working now after changing to `angular.mock.module`. Just had a typo too.

Answer (score 0):

Check the AngularJS [docs on injecting a module here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module). 
Also, heere's more info on [What is a Module?](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

When declaring your module in a unit test you dont use the anglar. prefix since you're using module from angular-mocks.js, not the same angular.module you normally use for defining controllers, services, etc.

Your unit test code line 3 should look like this:
    beforeEach(module('myapp.test'));